# Shortening code with multiple similar "while"-statements

Tags: python

Very basic question probably, but writing my first program and did not know what to search for to find the answer.

I have a while statement that looks something like this:

```
while number > 9999 or number < 0 or number == 1111 or number == 2222 or number == 3333...
```

And goes on until I get to 9999. Lots of code that probably can be shortened, am I correct? Not sure about where I could read about the grammar for this, so someone could also link me there!

Would be glad if anyone could help! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the *modulo* operator:

```
while number > 9999 or number < 0 or (number % 1111 == 0 and number != 0):
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work as written for the case `number = 0`.  Your logic would return `True`, but the the logic in the question would return `False`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried looking in the documentation for modulo, but I don't quite understand how it works and why it is applied in this context. Care to explain?

Comment: @root I think that now it shall conform to the question's logic.. no ?

Comment: @DavidHasselberg check this link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm In general, the modulo operator divides the 1st operand by the 2nd one & returns the remainder of the division. In this case, `number % 1111 == 0` means that `number` could be divided by 1111, which also means that `number` could be **1111**, **2222**, **3333** etc..

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the first two statements

```
number > 9999 or number < 0
```

into a single one by using set theory

```
number not in range(0,9999)
```

The rest you can check with a simple modulo operation:

```
not number % 1111
```

Whenever the operation above is called on `number` it will return either 0 or something unequal zero. For example `1 % 3 = 1` (we divide a smaller number by a greater one so we just get the smaller number as a result), `4 % 2 = 0` (because `4/2 = 2*2` so no remainder is left hence the 0 at the end) etc.

In Python `True` is the same as `1` and `False` is the same as `0`. We want the loop to keep going until `number` has such a value that can be divided by 1111 without any remainder so we have to negate the statement. Let's see an example how this works:

*Let's say that `number = 53`. In this case we have `number/1111 = 53/1111 = 53` because of the modulo parameter `1111`. This means that we get `True` (since True == 53 != 0 == False) and after negating it with the `not` operator we get a `False` (because `not True` is always `False` and vice versa). The `while` loop stops when its statement becomes `True`.*

Since we want to check if either one is `True` we can do:

```
while (number not in range(0,9999)) or (not number % 1111):
  # do something
```

If you want to exclude the 0 from the range you can simply go for `not in range(1,9999)`.

Comment: `[0, 9999]` is a list with two items, not a range of integers between 0 and 9999. Use `range(0, 1000)` (or `xrange(0, 1000)` in Python 2).

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to write this as normal text (mathematical formulation) but then decided to include it as code and forgot to change it accordingly. I've updated my answer.